# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.*** is not a function in React-redux app while calling a function from redux container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, containers

I have a react app with redux implemented and I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.updateDimensions is not a function

while executing the App.js:-

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWindowDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions);
  }

  updateWindowDimensions() {
    this.props.updateDimensions(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  render() { .....
```

The AppContainer.js file:-

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import { UPDATE_DIMENSIONS } from "../actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    screenWidth: state.screenSize.screenWidth,
    screenHeight: state.screenSize.screenHeight
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    updateDimensions: (screenWidth, screenHeight) => {
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_DIMENSIONS, screenWidth, screenHeight });
    }
  };
};

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default AppContainer;
```

This is the index.js, where the AppContainer is being called:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import AppContainer from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

let store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route component={AppContainer} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I believe this is a common error and I have looked everywhere and there seems to be no obvious flaw in the code. Not sure where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

in index.js:-

import AppContainer from "./App";

should be

import AppContainer from "./AppContainer";

ugh! This would have been so much easier if React threw an error saying 'AppContainer not found in ./App.js'

Update:-

I also had another error that was fixed by adding the following:-

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: *"This would have been so much easier if React threw an error saying 'AppContainer not found in ./App.js'"* -- You might want to give a shot at TypeScript, which can detect these kinds of annoying errors during compilation.

Comment: you can use arrow functions instead of binding

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot :

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary call to parent constructor

Comment: @Vivek, thanks, I got past the initial error I was facing, but there was another error after that. And adding the constructor fixed that.

Comment: @rawcode, will you please upvote if it helps you? and also accept the answer , if it is the answer ?

Comment: Upvoted, but this is not the answer to the initial question.

Comment: This constructor does not provide any value here. If you open up the developer console, you can see react's warning about `Useless constructor..`.